# IIS URL Rewrite Root to SubDirectory as a permanent with masking

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I have ASP.NET hosting from DiscountASP. I hosted a wordpress website in a sub-directory, namely `wordpress`. The domain is - let's say - `ghulamustafa.com`. Now I want to achieve that if I type `ghulamustafa.com` then it should show in the browser as `ghulamustafa.com` but not `ghulamustafa.com/wordpress`.

Comment: You don't have to be an expert to use such a simple module. There are already tons of examples over the internet, and you just need to carefully run a few experiments to learn the concepts. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Well, I did try a lot of them. Nothing worked for me. I believe it is because of the directory where all files are piled up.